# Gitlab-ci alpine image : Host key verification failed

Tags: linux, ssh, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux

In gitlab I build my job with a **maven image**, then copy the jar to the ssh server -> it works fine.

For a php project, I try to use **alpine image**. But I get rejected with '**Host key verification failed**'.

The server and the key are the same.

**Not working**:

```
image: alpine:latest
stages:
  - deploy
deploy:
  before_script:
    - apk add --update openssh-client bash
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - bash -c 'ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")'
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ssh root@devsb01 "ls"
```

**Working**:

```
  image: maven:3.6.0-jdk-10-slim
   stages:
      - deploy
   deploy:
      before_script:
        - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
        - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && mkdir -p ~/.ssh && echo "$KNOWN_HOST" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
      stage: deploy
      script:
        - ssh root@devsb01 "ls"
```

I think this has to do with the way the ssh key is add.

Comment: Got the exact same problem with an apline image when trying to connect in ssh to my vpn. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

try adding theses two lines:

```
- mkdir ~/.ssh
- ssh-keyscan -t rsa devsb01 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

It works for me!

Your file will look like that:

```
image: alpine:latest
stages:
  - deploy
deploy:
  before_script:
    - apk add --update openssh-client bash
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - bash -c 'ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")'
    - mkdir ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan -t rsa devsb01 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ssh root@devsb01 "ls"
```

Comment: Do you know why is the need to fetch server public keys?