# How to pull submodules with --remote within Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I need my Gitlab CI to update submodules with `--remote` flag so that the HEAD is set to the remote's HEAD. After a bit of Googling I found that I need to set `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` to `none` and run `git submodule update --recursive --remote  --init` manually:

```
variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: none

before_script:
  - apk add git || ( apt-get update && apt-get -y install git )
  - git submodule update --recursive --remote  --init

test:build:
  services:
  - docker:dind
  image: ubuntu
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  script:
  - echo "done
```

Unfortunately I'm getting a CI failure (names edited):

```
$ git submodule update --recursive --remote  --init
Submodule 'current_project_name/submodule_project_name' (ssh://git@gitlab.someserver.net:9931/someorg/submodule_project_name.git) registered for path 'current_project_name/submodule_project_name'
Cloning into '/builds/someorg/current_project_name/current_project_name/submodule_project_name'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'ssh://git@gitlab.someserver.net:9931/someorg/submodule_project_name.git' into submodule path '/builds/someorg/current_project_name/current_project_name/submodule_project_name' failed
Failed to clone 'current_project_name/submodule_project_name'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/builds/someorg/current_project_name/current_project_name/submodule_project_name'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'ssh://git@gitlab.someserver.net:9931/someorg/submodule_project_name.git' into submodule path '/builds/someorg/current_project_name/current_project_name/submodule_project_name' failed
Failed to clone 'current_project_name/submodule_project_name' a second time, aborting
```

I can see that the CI does have permissions to clone that `submodule_project_name` because if I set `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` e.g. to `recursive`, CI manages to pull it (but it's not `--remote`, so it doesn't work the way I want). Unfortunately when my `before_script` tries to do it, I'm getting the error. How can I bypass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52548491/6309) updating the `~/.ssh/.known_hosts` file, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55775059/6309).

This is not needed when [fetching the submodules *before* the script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42224451/6309) (which is not what you are doing with `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` set to `NONE`)

With dind (Docker In Docker), consider also [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/rebuilt-ci-runner-and-now-i-get-host-key-verification-failed/3869/3), regarding ssh-add for private keys, and `.dockerini` / `.dockerenv` SSH directives.

The [OP d33tah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1091116/d33tah) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386389/how-to-pull-submodules-with-remote-within-gitlab-ci/56388562?noredirect=1#comment99388251_56388562):

> I actually didn't add any key, assuming that since Gitlab CI's defaults can pull the key, I should be able to as well.
>   Then I found that docs say that I needed a deploy key and I added one

Yes: adding the public key on Gitlab side is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately disabling strict host checking only changed the error to "Permission denied, please try again.".

Comment: Are those private keys passphrase protected?

Comment: I actually didn't add any key, assuming that since Gitlab CI's defaults can pull the key, I should be able to as well. Then I found that docs say that I needed a deploy key and I added one, but couldn't re-add it to the other submodule I was using... and after some frustrating digging, I realized I don't need to re-add it, just find and enable it. So, it looks like I made a bit of (reversible) mess in the process, but the project works now. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @d33tah Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: sure, just wanted to double-check that CI works well before upvoting and marking as solved. Thanks for the reminder ;)